# Change Dymanic memory allocation to preallocated upon program start

Tags: c++

I have a class called shape and a few derived class, such as circle, rectangle, poly (max 8 point).

A _Point struct contains x and y for coordinate.

So for circle, it contain a _Point and radius; rectangle contain 2 _Point and poly contain 8 _Point.

Every time when an object is created, memory is allocated by using new and when changed/edited to different shape type, it will be deleted, memory released and new memory allocated for the new shape.

This will cause fragmentation as i am using it on embedded system. 
Hence, i am thinking to pre-allocate memory when program start using new with the largest shape (e.g 10 copies of poly, 10 being the max shape user can create) and when user create a circle shape for the 3rd item, i will just typecast that particular chunk of memory. Is this workable? Can C++ accept typecast like normal C and how to do it in C++. The memory will be freed only upon program ends.

Thanks.

Comment: You can use placement new to use a preallocated chunk of memory.

Comment: I believe using your search engine of choice for "C++ custom memory allocator" will give you enough literature and examples to get started

Comment: Hello, please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Can you provide some code?. And as for typecasts: you can try [`std::dynamic_cast<>()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) as you're using inheritance.

Comment: You can overload the new and delete operators. It's a bit fiddly, but it gives you low-level control over which memory is used where.

Answer (score -1):

Not a clean design but just a hint of what you are trying to do. Idea is to keep all the data requirements of all possible Shapes in Base class and implement the behaviour depending upon type of Shape using Derived classes.

```
struct _Point
{
    float x, y;
};

class Data
{
    protected:
        _Point points[8];  //max 8 as required.
};

class Behaviour_1 : public Data
{
    public:
    void Set(_Point x, _Point y)
    {
        points[0] = x;
        points[1] = y;
    }
    void Draw()
    {
        //use points[0] and points[1]
        cout << "Drawing Line ----" << endl;
        cout << "X coordinates: " << points[0].x << ", " << points[0].y << endl;
        cout << "Y coordinates: " << points[1].x << ", " << points[1].y << endl;
    }
};

class Behaviour_2 : public Data
{
    public:
    void Set(_Point x, float radius)
    {
        points[0] = x;
        points[1].x = radius;
    }

    void Draw()
    {
        //use points[0] and points[1].x
        cout << "Drawing Circle ----" << endl;
        cout << "Center coordinates: " << points[0].x << ", " << points[0].y << endl;
        cout << "Radius : " << points[0].x << endl;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    // your code goes here
    _Point x = {10, 20};
    _Point y = {30, 50};
    float radius = 60.0f;

    Data shape;
    Behaviour_1 *Line = (Behaviour_1 *)(&shape);
    Line->Set(x, y);
    Line->Draw();

    Behaviour_2 *Cicle = (Behaviour_2 *)(&shape);
    Cicle->Set(x, radius);
    Cicle->Draw();

    return 0;
}

Output:
Drawing Line ----
X coordinates: 10, 20
Y coordinates: 30, 50
Drawing Circle ----
Center coordinates: 10, 20
Radius : 10
```

In above classes:

- `Data` can be `Shape` having all the necessary data required for any kind of `Shape`.
- `Behaviour_1` can be `Line` which uses only `points[0] and points[1]` as its end-points.
- `Behaviour_2` can be `Circle` which uses `points[0]` as center and `points[1].x` as radius.

Comment: This is really bad. The upcasts are UB (and will really break if you need members in any subclasses), you are wasting a bunch of points in each non-polygon.

Comment: @Caleth: Have already mentioned that only behaviors would be implemented by derived classes which would not have any data of their own. All the data requirement would be in base class.

Comment: The upcasts are still undefined. A conforming compiler can do literally anything with your example.

Comment: @Caleth: Its Downcast and not Upcast. Anyway, its correct that proper way to downcast via dynamic_cast would fail. "C Type" casting woks. See updated answer. Anyway, its bad design.

Comment: The cast "works" because it is a `reinterpret_cast` to a different type. That is UB. Your shape is not a Behaviour_1, nor is it a Behaviour_2, you cannot portably cast to those types

Comment: @Caleth: "reinterpret_cast to a different type. That is UB" correct but only when we are not aware or source and destination types and their behavior. Otherwise why `reinterpret_cast` exists?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136550/discussion-between-caleth-and-sameerkn).